# How to code sed to delete multiple lines after a keyword until next blank line reached

Tags: unix, sed

Can anyone advise me on how to code a sed script that can be used to update a text file as follows:

Each time a line in the file containing the character string 'Header_one' is encountered:
- delete the lines that immediately follow the 'Header_one' line until the next blank line is encountered.
- but dont delete the 'Header_one' line itself

So as an example, a file containing this:

```
Header_one
dkrjng
djsje

Header_two
cklrgjsj
djrhg

Header_one
drgbyj
efgjjm
cddess

Header_three
sdfvgg
ddddfy
```

Would be changed to:

```
Header_one

Header_two
cklrgjsj
djrhg

Header_one

Header_three
sdfvgg
ddddfy
```

I would be grateful for any guidance or solution.
Thanks,
James.

Comment: welcome to SO, here you are expected to show what you've tried yourself to solve this problem.. if you are new to `sed`, you can go through https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for some faqs and learning resources.. after you've some code that you are stuck with, you could ask here for help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/ would be a good starting point for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snip

`< InputFile sed -e '/Header_one/i Header_one' -e '/Header_one/,/s/d' > outputFile`

The idea here is to replace the content between 2 rows and replace it with a header (i.e. Header_one). The second `-e` part of the codes does delete the data between Header_one and space; while the first `-e` part replaces it with a new header `Header_one`.

InputFile and OutputFiles are simple redirections.

You can also look into: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637003/delete-lines-between-2-strings

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a stream editor, and although one popular version of sed provides an option that appears to make it edit files, I strongly advise against its use.  That said, you can produce the output you desire with:

```
sed -e '/Header_one/i\
Header_one\
\
' -e '/Header_one/,/^$/d' input
```

Note that it's a lot cleaner if you don't require keeping that blank line:

```
sed -e '/Header_one/p' -e '/Header_one/,/^$/d' input
```

Also:  `awk '/Header_one/{printf "Header_one\n\n"; next } 1' RS= ORS='\n\n' input`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
perl -ne ' {  print "Header_one\n" if /Header_one/ ; print if not /Header_one/../^$/ } '
```